# SASS Operation color times amount depreciated?

Tags: sass, codekit

What is the new way to do the following?

```
border-color: transparent lighten((#F1CE18 * 1.05), 5%);
```

CodeKit warns me:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 104 of 
/Users/r/Documents/anglicans/wordpress/wp-content/themes/afl_theme1/scss/_header.scss:
The operation `#F1CE18 times 1.05` is deprecated and will be an error in future versions.
```

I've looked over: [lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#other_color_functions](http://lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#other_color_functions)
but can't find out how to do this properly.

Comment: Why `#F1CE18 * 1.05`, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Why not make your #F1CE18 * 1.05 a variable and use that in your element styling?